# find_all with multiple expressions for tags that include both attribute values specified

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm working to pull all tags from an HTML file with both the attribute values h5 and ls3 but I'm not sure how to format the search so it doesn't return all instances of h5 and all instances of ls3.

```py
regex = re.compile('h5')
re2 = re.compile('ls3')

ly = []


for EachPart in soup.find_all("div", {"class": regex}):
    ly.append(EachPart)
```

This is currently only searching for h5 (as expected), but how can I format the `find_all` search to search for `re2` along with `regex`? Effectively, below I need to be pulling the tags that have h5 and ls3 and not the ones that are exclusively h5

Example HTML Tags:

```
<div class="t m0 x42 h5 y18b ff2 fs2 fc0 sc0 ls0 ws0">total </div>

<div class="t m0 xbd h5 y18b ff2 fs2 fc0 sc0 ls0 ws0"> </div>

<div class="t m0 x79 h5 y18b ff2 fs2 fc0 sc0 ls3 ws0">£m<span class="ls0"> </span></div>

<div class="t m0 x0 h5 y628 ff2 fs2 fc0 sc0 ls3 ws0">17.<span class="ls0"> <span class="_ _4"></span>Website policy<span class="_ _0"></span> </span></div>
```

Comment: post html example code

Comment: give link to html that you need to parse. Which class names you want to collect?

Answer (score 0):

Use css selectors with AND syntax. Below specifies elements with both attributes. More efficient than `find` and regex.

```
items = [item.text for item in soup.select('.ls3.h5')]
```